# Merging 2 SQL Server Databases Structures

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, entity-framework-5

My system started life as a single WinForms application with a single database using Entity Framework.  Down the line, the database was branched off to encompass a new system which was extended with new tables.  The main Employee table was renamed to Person, and all associated FK references were renamed with the term person in columns.

The existing system has since changed in terms of database structure with new tables added.

Something like:

[image: System History]

Now I want to bring the 2 databases in line, keeping the Person table over Employee.  I also need to bring the 2 Entity Frameworks together.  I need some tips and pointers on how to do this.

Luckily the new system is still in UAT so is not live.  I have base population scripts for this.

I use nHydrate to maintain both Entity Frameworks - DB First.  The database side of things I can cope with.  However, I am unsure of the best way to bring my Entity Frameworks back in line.

There are tools I have used to sync databases such as Red Gate's SQL Compare.  Also VS2013 has a nice SQL Schema Compare.

I have a couple thoughts on different ways to do this:

**Thought 1**

1. Manually add the changes through the EF database designer
2. Generate a new database
3. Script the data to copy from the initial system to the new database
4. Run Population scripts for the new system.

**Thought 2**

1. Manually add the changes through the EF database designer
2. Upgrade Existing System
3. Run Population scripts for the new system

**Thought 3**

1. Somehow merge the CSDL, MSL, SSDL files to Entity Framework with WinMerge for example
2. Upgrade Existing System
3. Run Population scripts for the new system

I am about to endeavour on this quest, possibly with Thought #3 unless anyone quickly posts responses on here.  I want to know how the community would go about this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought copy and paste from one model to the other would fail, but I tried that first and it did.  Also, the suggestion of merging the CSDL, MSL, SSDL files was also a no-go as they are generated in line with the database.

What I finally tried and also worked was to use Redgates SQL Compare:

1. Run SQL Compare on New System Changes and Existing System Changes.

   This generates an upgrade script which I run against the Existing System Changes.
2. Import the Database into the Model

   Refresh the EF Model from the Existing System Changes upgrade.
3. Generate a new database from the current EF Model - Merged Changes
4. Run SQL Compare on Initial DB and Merged Changes.

   Now I have a complete script to go from Initial DB to Merged Changes.

For the table I renamed in the existing changes, I had to tweak the script to copy the data before dropping the old table.  It took a little doing and trail and error but this works for me.

Hope it might help anyone in this position.